# LOg4j - Getting fileName is Null {The parameter is null: fileName}

Tags: java, logging, yaml, log4j

When I run my application am getting File Name is null
Log4j - Getting file Name is Null {The parameter is null: file Name}
LOg4j2.yaml :->

```
Configuration:
  status: debug
  packages: com.xyz.x.log

  appenders:
    Console:
      name: LogToConsole
      PatternLayout:
        #Pattern: "%reqId%msg%n"
         Pattern: "%d{YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %C{1} %L - %m%n"
    File:
      name: LogToFile
      PatternLayout:
        Pattern: "%d{YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  %C{1} %L - %m%n"

  Loggers:
    logger:
      - name: com.xyz.x
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToConsole
          - ref: LogToFile
      - name: org.springframework.security
        level: debug
        additivity: false
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: LogToConsole
          - ref: LogToFile
    Root:
      level: error
      AppenderRef:
        ref: LogToConsole
```

Error I am getting:

```
 File org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Arguments given for element File are invalid: field 'fileName' has invalid value 'null'
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:208)
```

Comment: When you configure a `FileAppender`, you need to specify a file for the appender's output. You do it using a `fileName` attribute.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  how to configure fileName in  yaml file any example

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `File` appender in order to add the *filename* property
For example:

```
File:
  name: LogToFile
  fileName: logs/yourLog.log
  PatternLayout:
    Pattern: "%d{YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  %C{1} %L - %m%n"
```